# Auto filter for an existing filter in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have sheet1(Netmark Inc 8-28-2014) with data and sheet2 with a front end having check boxes based on the check box selected filter should be applied in sheet1 so for the applied filter again there are some more sub check boxes under that under that main category if I select the sub check box the filer need to be applied with the first selected filter range.

Example

1. brand is a check box once we select it will list all the rows having Brand in the column A.
   Code for this filter is working as expected.
2. So now under check box Brand there are sub categories like Puma,nike so if i select an of the check boxes the previous filter should not be removed and current sub category filter should be applied.

Here i am getting an error message autofilter method of range class failed

Below is the code for the first check box

> ```
> Dim My_Range As Range
> Dim CalcMode As Long
> Dim ViewMode As Long
> Dim FilterCriteria As String
> Dim CCount As Long
> Dim WSNew As Worksheet
> Dim sheetName As String
> Dim rng As Range Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
>
>
>
>
>
> 'Set filter range on ActiveSheet: A1 is the top left cell of your filter range
> 'and the header of the first column, D is the last column in the filter range.
> 'You can also add the sheet name to the code like this :
> 'Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:D" & LastRow(Worksheets("Sheet1")))
> 'No need that the sheet is active then when you run the macro when you use this.
> Set My_Range = Sheets("Netmark Inc 8-28-2014").Range("A1:A404")
> My_Range.Parent.Select
>
> If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure = True Or _
>    My_Range.Parent.ProtectContents = True Then
>     MsgBox "Sorry, not working when the workbook or worksheet is protected", _
>            vbOKOnly, "Copy to new worksheet"
>     Exit Sub
> End If
>
> 'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation, EnableEvents, ....
> With Application
>     CalcMode = .Calculation
>     .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
>     .ScreenUpdating = False
>     .EnableEvents = False
> End With
> ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
> ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
> ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
> If (CheckBox1.Value = "True") Then
> 'Firstly, remove the AutoFilter
> My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
>
> 'Filter and set the filter field and the filter criteria :
> 'This example filter on the first column in the range (change the field if needed)
> 'In this case the range starts in A so Field 1 is column A, 2 = column B, ......
> 'Use "<>Netherlands" as criteria if you want the opposite
> My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CheckBox1.Caption
>
> Else
> My_Range.Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
> End If
> Sheets("Questionnaire").Select End Sub
> ```
>
> End Sub
>   >
>   Blockquote

Below is the code for the second checkbox.

> private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
>
> ```
> Set My_Range = Sheets("Netmark Inc 8-28-2014").Range("G1:G404")
> My_Range.Parent.Select
> My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:=CheckBox2.Caption
> Sheets("Questionnaire").Select End Sub
> ```

Answer (score 1):

In checkbox 2, your range is G1:G404 so your range is only 1 column wide but you are attempting to filter on the 7th column. The Field argument is relative to the range you are using, not the overall column in the sheet.

```
My_Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=CheckBox2.Caption
```